# Is there a way to test if AJAX is working on my Website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

Today is my first time I am working with AJAX. I am using the AJAX from the Google Servers.
That is my Code to import AJAX:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried some Code from AJAX, but somehow nothing worked, so i want to know, if its because I am using AJAX the wrong way, or if AJAX simply does not import/work.

Is there a way to test if AJAX is working on my Website?

Comment: The chances are you're not completely getting what [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax) is.

Comment: Yeah could be :3 But thats why im asking, now that i know that AJAX is working, i try to understand it more.

Comment: For you to proceed any further, you should absorb simple fact that `jQuery != AJAX`, furthermore, you [don't need](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) jQuery to do AJAX, [whatsoever](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). jQuery is a whole lot more than XHR-wrapper thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // This executes after jQuery loads
});
```

When you do something and you need to check you can use

```
if (typeof jQuery !="undefined")
```

Maybe you are using AJAX the wrong way

```
$.get("...url...",{"param":"value","param2":"value"},function(response){
//
});
```

You can leave the second parameter if you don't need to and you can get $.post instead of $.get

Comment: By the way AJAX is Asynchron Javascript and XML (nowadays JSON)
You are using jQuery which used for making AJAX requests (and for lots of more things)

Comment: ty, now i know, that AJAX is wokring and im just doing something wrong :D

`$(document).ready(function(){
  // This executes after jQuery loads
});`

worked for testing AJAX.

Comment: What you are using is jQuery :) AJAX is the name of the technology which is used for requests.
What is the code which is not working for you?

Comment: Well i am trying to understand AJAX/JQuery more so the Code that doesnt work, doesnt matter cause i try to solve this problem by myself for now so i can understand more. I am at the start if i need more help i Post a question. Thanks for your help guys :D